# Uninstall Postman and Vysor

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-16.04, postman

I have uninstalled chrome from my system ubuntu 16.04 first. I thought that the chrome applications would be uninstalled along with it. But I can see Vysor and Postman in my application list. I tried uninstalling by the command

```
sudo apt-get purge postman

sudo apt-get purge vysor
```

But that didnt work.
Is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If Vysor and Postman are chrome extensions, you should uninstall from chrome menu. Tools->Extensions, find the extension on the list and click uninstall.

In my case I also had the Vysor icon on the main menu, and after uninstalled from chrome extensions it disappears automatically.

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo apt-get purge postman
```

If not work:

```
sudo snap remove postman
```

Comment: What makes you think Postman was installed via Snap?

Comment: @Chris yes exactly